# npm run error Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get the current npm bin executed with elastic-beanstalk as container command, but I'm getting the following error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'bin' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.3
4 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
4 verbose stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/osenv/osenv.js:60:29
4 verbose stack     at Object.exports.(anonymous function) [as path] (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/osenv/osenv.js:15:15)
4 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.bin (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/bin.js:15:20)
4 verbose stack     at Object.commandCache.(anonymous function) (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:159:13)
4 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:84:30)
4 verbose stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
4 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
5 verbose cwd /var/app/ondeck/application
6 verbose Linux 4.14.47-56.37.amzn1.x86_64
7 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "bin"
8 verbose node v8.11.3
9 verbose npm  v5.6.0
10 error Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

When I execute it from the terminal all works fine and I'll get the `~/node_modules/.bin/` directory.

Any ideas why ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you post the command you are executing?

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin
npm bin`

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a path before the execution:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin
npm bin
```

Thanks !